# Error calling SOAP method: Error deserializing message

Tags: java, soap

I have a shipping module created with java that uses soap. When trying to ship a package I get the following error message that prevents fedex shipping rates to display:

```
Sorry, there was an error in processing this form action. Please report the error or try again later.
(Error calling SOAP method: Error deserializing message: Can't locate ShipRequest/FedEx/SOAP/Elements /FuelSurchargePercent.pm in @INC 
(@INC contains: /usr/lib/interchange 
    /var/lib/transactions/lib2
    /usr
    /lib/interchange/lib
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i686-linux
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8
    /usr/local/lib
    /perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i686-linux
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
 .) at (eval 3213) line 3.
 at line 2 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/SOAP/WSDL/Expat/Base.pm line 18 .
```

The shipping module and fedex api was working, but now I get this message.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Point me in some direction as to the problem causing the error?

thank you
steve

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume you are calling the Fedex API's on Fedex's servers.

This is an error on their side. It looks like they changed something with their configuration, or server setup, which is causing this error to be thrown. The actual error deals with a Webservice written in PERL can not find some required dependencies. To put this error in the Java world, it would be like removing JAR files from the classpath at runtime.

Comment: Yes, the fedex api connects with the fedex server. The error message seems to be looking for this file /FuelSurchargePercent.pm in this folder locate ShipRequest/FedEx/SOAP/Elements 

I checked the folder on my server and this file is not there but there are similar files for other services. I'm not sure how to create this file. Not sure how to use SOAP-WSDL-2.00_23 Any ideas?

Comment: This probably isn't a file you are going to be creating yourself. I'm guessing, without knowing more about your contract with FedEx, that this is a file you should be getting from them.